# Search for character present in input in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have one numeric variable (stored as VARCHAR2 in oracle DB for some business requirements). The batch file accepts this variable from the user where user has to enter a number.

I want the batch file to check if user is not entering a character, if yes, then re-direct control to start of input where user has to enter number variable.

In case of no input, default value of this number is allocated in calling Stored Procedure.

I have the below code so far:-

```
}:enter_input
set nullinp=
set input=
echo.
set /P input="Enter the input (default size is 50): "
echo.
if "%input%"=="%nullinp%" (
set /A input= -1)

:validate_input
echo select to_char('%input%') from dual; > %dir%\validate_input.txt
echo exit >> validate_input.txt

echo "%dbpwd%" | %connStr% @%dir%\validate_input.txt > %log%\validate_input.log

findstr "ORA-" %log%\validate_input.log
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto message1
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto catch_error

:catch_error
   cls
   echo.  
  echo "ERROR ==> Check no entered"
  echo 
  echo.
  echo.
  goto enter_input
```

I would like to add condition to the above to check if the entered input contains any character value, then the control must go back to :enter_input.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
echo(%input%|findstr "^[0-9-][0-9]*$" >nul && echo only numbers || goto:enter_input
```

Comment: I would like to add Error message when incorrect entry is made using the above statement, how can i achieve it ?

Comment: try this as replacement: `|| (echo ERROR & goto:enter_input)`

Comment: One thing im noting is that, when I enter correct number value...a file isopen in my notepad with query (select to_char('100') from dual;) and control goes straight to it with Command prompt still running the operation.How to ignore this control shift ??

Comment: Please give an example for a `number value` that shifts control. What notepad do you use?

Comment: On entering any valid number value, the control shifts to notepad and it opens "validate_input.txt" with Select query (as provided above with number entered as input variable). I have to manually go back to command prompt and continue forward and close the file opened in notepad manually after all my operations are over.

Comment: if you have a file `validate_input.cmd` or `validate_input.bat`  or an other file `validate_input.???` where `???`  is assigned to a command/program, the `call:validate_input`  command will execute this. You should rename your jump label, it can't be the same as a file name.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use an external utility, I would recommend a small program I wrote called EditV32.exe (or EditV64.exe for 64-bit Windows). It can read user input into an environment variable, and it also has **-n** option to force numeric input only. You can download it from here:

https://westmesatech.com/?page_id=19

For example:

```
set INPUT=
editv32 -p "Enter the input (default size is 50): " -n
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 set INPUT=50
```

Exit code of 2 means user pressed ENTER without entering anything so in this case you would assign value of 50.

Also note that you should use EditV64.exe rather than EditV32.exe if you are using 64-bit version of Windows.

Bill

Comment: Sorry, cannot use third party code here. Strictly not allowed.

Comment: In this case I would recommend PowerShell rather than trying to do it in cmd.exe's primitive scripting language.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about Power Shell  please ?

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell example:

```
do {
  $response = Read-Host "Enter the input (default size is 50): "
  if ( $response -eq "" ) {
    $size = 50
  }
  else {
    $size = $response -as [Int]
  }
  if ( -not $size ) {
    Write-Host "Invalid size"
  }
}
until ( $size -gt 0 )
"You entered: $size"
```

Comment: Readers can ignore the drive-by downvote. The OP asked for more information on PowerShell.